# Merge Request: [wings-of-liberty] -> [starcraft-2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merging

the [wings-of-liberty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wings-of-liberty) tag exists separate to [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2), and is only used on questions that have the Starcraft 2 tag anyway.

Comment: So... how is this an obvious merge, but the SF4 merge isn't...? http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5554/lets-merge-tagstreet-fighter-4-and-tagsuper-street-fighter-4-to-tagstree

Comment: @Decency - I don't know much about SF4, but Aren't those different games though? With their own tactics, gameplay etc?

Comment: Other than some balance changes and new characters and stages added, they're entirely just updates of the same game. The first version and the current one are far more similar in gameplay than WoL and HotS are.

Comment: @Decency - As a layman to fighting/hand to hand combat games, from my perspective you just described sequels to that genre in general. Does that mean all sequels of a particular fighting game should be kept under one 'series' tag? A better example: what about AoE2 and AoE2HD?

Comment: SF4 is the sequel to SF3, which is the sequel to SF2. Much like StarCraft 2 is the sequel to SC1. SC1 and SC:BW are the same game using the same mechanics and game systems, much like WoL and HotS, much like SF4 and its half dozen varieties. Either way, conversation would be better kept in the other topic.

Comment: OK, well from Starcraft 2's perspective, HotS is an expansion, and cannot be played separately to WoL. Can the same be said about SSF4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds reasonable.

The large majority of "Wings of Liberty" questions would, by necessity, have to refer to either Wings of Liberty-exclusive maps, or achievements, which means that they could be appropriately identified by the map / achievement name alone, making the tag redundant.

I don't see a possible scenario where someone asks about the campaign and it is unclear whether they're referring to a WoL mission or a HotS mission.

Comment: I agree with the merge in this case, but I have an issue with your reasoning. The point of a tag isn't to make questions unambiguous. The title and body text should be doing that. The point of a tag is to make questions about certain things easier to find. By your logic we shouldn't ever have sub-tags, which can be very useful in the right circumstances.

Comment: @StrixVaria - Is that not where synonyms come in?

Comment: @Robotnik I mean something like minecraft-redstone is good to have as a separate tag from minecraft, because you can specifically be an expert in redstone. If you're looking for redstone questions you shouldn't have to sift through all the rest of the minecraft questions as well. I'm not sure what you're asking me.

Comment: @StrixVaria - oh yes, I get you now. At the same time I still reckon WoL and HotS should be grouped. However, multiplayer strategies and build orders would be a good thing to keep separate from single player/achievement questions in that case

Comment: @StrixVaria I might agree with a more broad "campaign versus multiplayer" (and I believe that may have already been discussed, in fact?), but the Wings of Liberty campaign hasn't *changed* as a result of HotS (like the multiplayer has).